# Does PostgreSQL use pg_largeobject table internally?

Tags: sql, postgresql, blob, lob, largeobject

I want to clean all large objects created by users and I'm using the following script:

```
SELECT lo_unlink(l.loid) FROM pg_largeobject l
```

Is it safe operation? Does postgresql use large objects for it's internal use?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That is quite safe as far as PostgreSQL is concerned.

It is always OK to select from a system catalog, and `lo_unlink` is safe.

PostgreSQL doesn't use large objects internally.